# QuartzCore.h - Shadow layer disrupts all view animations

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, shadow, quartz-core

When I use even a single shadow-layered User Interface object on my `ViewController`, transition animations (navigation push-pop animations) and scrolling animations seem to slow down and get disrupted, both on device (iOS 5.1, iphone 4S) and on simulator (5.1).

I understand there is some extra drawing on the shadow layer, but is it normal that a simple shadow layer blocks the smoothness of the whole view? Is there a key point that I am missing or is there another way to put shadow on views which will be smoother?

I am sharing the code I use for applying shadows on my user interface objects;

.h (putting the required header file just in case anyone tries to use the code)

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

.m

```
    self.someView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
    self.someView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.someView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
    self.someView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
```

Comment: This has been asked many, many times. The first thing to try is the answer to the linked question: set the `shadowPath` property on your layer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot easier on the resources if you'll use an image as a shadow, as the layers and visible pixels won't have to be recalculated as many times as with a code generated-shadow.

Comment: generally I am using shadows on holder UIViews with only background colors and they exist on multiple places with different sizes. I just don't want to create tons of resources. Any way to create a generic, lets say white backgrounded and shadowed background image and make it the size we want ? If you would suggest a way to use resources in such efficient way, that would be really great

Comment: @Bartu I'd make the 'smallest' version of the shadow background, so that it has the corners I'd want and a 1px*1px resizable area in the center (and in the middle of edges also). Then just use [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:) method on your _UIImage_.

Comment: thanks for your idea, I will give it a try. Although the performance increased quite much after applying shadowPath and enabling render.